# Get the setter/getter of a style property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, setter, getter

To get the setter and getter of "style", we can do this:

`var style_get = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, "style").get`

`var style_set = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, "style").set`

What if I wanted to get the setter and getter of e.g. style.color? How can I get that?

Comment: Well, since your code doesn't work (throws a TypeError, `HTMLElement.prototype.style` doesn't exist), I'm not sure...

Comment: You generally can't get code for native objects.

Comment: Ian, there must be some other way in Chrome, if you're using that. Works in Firefox.

Comment: Why do you want this anyways? It doesn't make sense for `HTMLElement` to have a `style` on its `prototype` (that would mean every element shared the same `style` object). Why do you need the getter and setter for the HTMLElement interface anyways?

Comment: "Why do you want this anyways?" Reasons. "(that would mean every element shared the same style object)" -- that's not correct... anyway it is a moot point, since FF allows it (and they are different style objects). I'm sure Chrome does too in some way, or will.